# GIS to long and lat

Tags: php, gis

I am using mySQL for my GIS shape information, so in DB I have columb called SHAPE with for example [GEOMETRY - 25 Б] And when I try to edit it I have an `informatioon like 'POINT(3.5540809 51.7823656)',4926` 
How can I get this value becaouse when I try the $`query = SELECT FROM 'shape_files' WHERE id = 1` 
and when I try to get the value from the query by `dd($query);` I gave something like

```
    array:1 [▼
  0 => {#207 ▼
    +"SHAPE": b"æ\x10\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00pÇ@C¤+÷?\!¬Æ\x12gN@"
  }
]
```

How can I take this value.

Answer (score 2):

you may use `astext(fieldname)` or `asbinary(fieldname)` to get  WKT and WKB formats respectively and use then a library like one of those

- geoPHP https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP
- creof/geo https://packagist.org/packages/creof/geo

to transform the data to something useful